# Building main reference table from multiple tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert data from `tbl_user` and `tbl_applist` into `tbl_MainRef(fld_userid, fld_appId)` table.

`tbl_applist` has 20 rows which need to be inserted into `tbl_MainRef` against each single row from `tbl_user` table.

So it should look like this in mainref

```
 1, userid1, appid1 
 2, userid1, appid2  
 3, userid1, appid3  
 4, userid1, appid4  
 5, userid1, appid5
 6, userid2, appid1
 7, userid3, appid2
```

and so on ... I've tried CTE and also inserting using multiple tables but I cant get it to do the recursive whole app table per user.

Comment: Hi bsingh! Welcome to StackOverflow! :) What did you try so far? What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a `cross join`?

```
insert into mainref (userid, appid)
    select u.userid, a.appid
    from tbl_user u cross join
         tbl_applist a;
```

You can run the `select` query to see what this does.